# ASP.NET still run without code files, how?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have to inherit an ASP.NET 1.1 website of company. The website's still running smoothly. I get a copy of it and then convert it to ASP.NET 2.0, and Visual Studio 2008 shows errors:

```
Parser Error

Description: An error occurred during the parsing of a resource required to service this request. Please review the following specific parse error details and modify your source file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: Could not load type 'POMan.Support'.

Source Error:

Line 1:  <%@ Page Language="vb" AutoEventWireup="false" Codebehind="Default.aspx.vb" Inherits="POMan.Support"%> 
Line 2:  <head>
Line 3:      <style type="text/css">


Source File: /Functions/Support/Default.aspx    Line: 1
```

The truth is, there is no Default.aspx.vb in the folder, and there's no POMan.Support class/namespace.

I don't know why the original web site still run. How can I get it to run on .NET 2.0?

Answer (score 3):

Have you got this by pulling it from the webserver? If so the code behind would be compiled into an assembly in the bin folder (don't forget that .Net 1.1 only had what are now referred to as "Web applications" rather than the "web site" format that was introduced with .Net 2

Answer (score 1):

if the site has been compiled - ie has a bin folder with dlls in it then it doesn't need the code behind files to run. however if you what to change anything you will need them in order to recompile the dlls.

Josh

Comment: This isn't strictly true. It's possible for a web site project to have a bin folder.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need source files (.vb or .cs) to run a website - those files get compiled into the .dlls.  If you don't have access to the source, you can 
a) send a pleading message to whomever developed the source originally, 
b) search through your source control (eg subversion), or 
c) reverse-engineer the .dlls using something like the .net reflector (http://www.red-gate.com/products/reflector/index.htm)

I don't get any hits on Google for POMan.Support, so I'm assuming it's a private namespace internal to your project.

Lance

Comment: yep, POMan.Support is a private namespace. :). Actually, I'm using .NET  reflector to discover what behind the .dll file